# Team programming

Tags: android

We are a little group of developers who are going to develop apps for android. We are using Eclipse for that. We need an application to mantain project synchronization between different computers. Is there any application for that? I mean that we create a project or a workspace in eclipse and all the files are synchronized with other computers.

Comment: Ever heard of Source Control Software?
Try this: http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/IntroductionToVersionControl.html
Or this: http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html

Comment: no, i didnt even know what i was looking for. We are a young group just have started studying software development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a version control system

- [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

Note that the first three do not require a central store whilst subversion does.

I would suggest bazaar; I have used it and it is very very easy to get introduced to and supports plenty of workflows.

Comment: ok thanks for both the application and the type of application i am looking. Now i can look for it in google if i do not like the one you show

Comment: I like Subversion better. Perforce is also another option but Licensing can be a bit overpriced for a small group.

Comment: Please note this is an English site please make links to English pages (and also the home sites rather than wikipedia)

Comment: Thanks for the edits Mark I did not notice the that google returned french pages to me.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: As the other answers state, you are looking for a version control system. Dropbox is not that.

The instances where I've found it to be most useful is when I am collaborating on a project with someone who is not a programmer. If the other person is supplying resources (images, videos, text content etc...) dropbox simplifies this process because they can put the files directly into the project folder and it will be immediately sync'd back to me.

For very small teams I find dropbox to be very helpful. You can put your project workspace into Dropbox and share the folder with your team. Then your project will get auto sync'd to their computers if they have the Dropbox client installed.

If you have more than a few people(or you have multiple people who could be working on the same piece of the project) I definitely recommend the same tools that have been linked in the other answers.

Comment: we are just 2 (maybe 3), i will try it

Comment: dropbox ain't no good for development. Even if you are only two people commits history is very important overtime. Branching as well is one of the best ways of splitting the sources (instead of a simple copy/paste) as you lose the merge/bundle capability. Use software made for that purpose, dropbox is only for file sharing.

Comment: I agree with the part about commit history(which dropbox is capable of with its file revisions system), but I have found the blanket statement "dropbox ain't no good for development" to be not entirely accurate. I have personally used it quite effectively for this purpose(though it is certainly not the correct tool for every situation). It definitely has its limitations, and there are more complete tools to do the job in many situations. But depending on the team and the situation I believe dropbox can serve as a simple and effective tool to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I did not say it was not usable for development; I said it was not good since it is not targeted to that purpose. File sharing and version control are two different things not to be mingled. Moreover with Bazaar, git and mercurial you can work offline... dropbox cannot offer this capability whereas if you ain't got connection you ain't committing a dime. Please point the guy to the right direction :)

Comment: thanks to your answers i will take it into acount. jus a question, if i use git mercury etc, i need some internet service dont i?

Comment: it depends on what workflow you are setting up. Please have a look at http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Workflows